# SQL: Use a loop to generate X number of TEMP tables, then join X number of temp tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a flexible query, which will loop and generate X number of temp tables. Following the loop, the query will then be able to join all X of these temp tables.

Thus, I need a query that can generate 1,2,3,...,n temp tables, and then be able to join all of them, no matter the amount. They will all be join on an 'ID' PRIMARY KEY, with each table having the EXACT same ID values...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You'll need a dynamic SQL query, search for it in docs of your RDBMS

Comment: Sounds more like a big [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps all you really need is a numbers (or tally) table - a little searching will find many examples of generating them.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you need stored procedures.

And then in the stored procedure you create a variable where you dynamically create your join query.

And then you use exec to run the contents of the variable.

It's considered very bad practice but it make it possible to do some things that would normally be impossible, most notably return different number of columns depending on the data.